# icloud keychain is turned on but does not suggest passwords

Tags: iphone, icloud, safari, password, keychain

For a while now safari on my iphone (iphone 6s, ios 13) has stopped suggesting strong passwords when I am signing up for new webstites online.

iCloud keychain *is turned on*, however safari will not suggest new passwords. I have also tried switching keychain off and on again, and switching password autofill off and on again.

Comment: Does your iPhone automatically fill in recorded usernames & passwords for the related web sites?

Comment: @Alper yes, saved passwords and login details are able to be autofilled

Comment: Safari is unable to recognize the password forms in certain web sites properly. This may prevent it from suggesting a strong password for those sites. Have you tried changing your password at a site where Safari previously suggested a strong password?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. I have been unable to find any website where suggest password works!